# How to solve touch input lag for Windows 8 game?

Tags: input, windows-8, touch, lag

I am currently developing a game for Windows 8 using C++ with pure XAML (no DirectX.) At some point, I start noticing a lag when touch inputs occur (e.g. Tap.) Mouse click (or other mouse events) doesn't cause the same lag issue. I also notice the more touch fingers, the more lag happens.

This issue seems to be specific to XAML apps only, either C++ or C#. I tried with sample Direct3D project and all seems fine.

I created a clean slate C++ XAML app with almost nothing except 1 Ellipse control that has a Storyboard to animate it around the page, then tried disabling all inputs on root control by setting IsRightTapEnabled/IsHoldingEnabled/IsDoubleTapEnabled/ManipulationMode/IsTapEnabled/IsHitTestVisible to False. But the lag still happens when triggering touch inputs.

So from this, I'm sure there has to be something wrong at the fundamental level. The app almost does nothing and the lag still occurs.

There are games like Hydro Thunder and Jetpack Joyride on Windows 8 that also have a touch input lag issue (see http://wrtapps.com/2012/12/windows-rt-games-suffering-from-touch-screen-input-lag/). Somehow they managed to fix it already.

I believe there must be a way to fix this (as somehow guys from Halfbrick already did so.) It's almost like touch on Windows 8 is eating more CPU than usual. But I couldn't figure out how to prevent that. I couldn't find any other articles blogging about this issue also. Now I run out of clue :(

Any suggestions to this issue would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your sample?  Just put it on http://SkyDrive.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced a very similar error within my directX C++ App (using a simple XAML-Page) and tracked the problem down to a visual feedback that is shown when touch occurs.

As with your program, mouse input didn't affect performance at all.

I got it solved by disabling the visual touch feedback:

You have to get the [PointerVisualizationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.pointervisualizationsettings.getforcurrentview) for the current view and set the
[ContactFeedbackEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.pointervisualizationsettings.iscontactfeedbackenabled.aspx) property to false.

Doing this removed any perfomance drops on touch. Maybe you just want to give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That did solve the issue for me. Though I still see a little lag when 4-5 fingers touch on the screen. But this should be good enough for now :)